# How to disable hit effect in Painkiller?

Tags: painkiller-series

normal gameplay screenshot:

[image: gameplay screenshot]

hit image:

[image: hit image]

The game blurs the screen when the player character takes melee hit, the effect lasts around three seconds and isn't caused by ranged attacks. This happens in all [Painkiller games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painkiller_(video_game)) released so far (Painkiller, Overdose, Resurrection, Redemption, Recurring Evil) with the exception of Hell & Damnation.
As all games in the series up to Painkiller: Redemption appear to use the same engine, one fix could work for all five titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to modify `LScripts.pak` file to disable the effect, but since [extracting is a complex process](http://pkzone.org/how-to-create-a-mod-in-pak-file-format/) and overwrites game files I recommend using a mod. Download "[hit blur fix](http://www.pkzone.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=106)" and extract `LScripts` folder to the data folder in the game directory.

Unfortunately the mod is created for the original Painkiller game and doesn't work with the sequels without modification according to the author.

[source](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1306710742)

---

Regarding the extraction method, change the line (in `LScripts.pak`):

```
    if self._Time >= self._TimeOut then return end
```

to

```
    if self._Time <= self._TimeOut then return end
```

Comment: [Instructions for the extraction method](http://www.pkzone.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=106)  aren't entirely clear, I'm not sure if there's a file (`TPlayerHit.CProcess`) inside `LScripts.pak` which should be modified instead.